# Sending message to Fragment within TabHost in FragmentTabPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'm using the FragmentTabsPager class from

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabsPager.html

in one of my apps. The FragmentTabsPager contains 3 Fragments. Within my layout, I have a list on the left side which I want to send a message (onListItemClick) to the current Fragment within the FragmentTabsPager. I'm having serious difficulty getting the current Fragment instance within the pager.

Sorry, I know this is vague but if anyone has an idea that would be great.

The mechanics of passing the message from the List fragment is fine, I can get the message into my FragmentTabsPager class no problem. It's getting the message into the current Fragment within the TabHost that's causing me stress.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do here. A Fragment is generally just a Layout. What message are you trying to send to it? Are you trying to update the UI in the current fragment?

Comment: @C0deAttack I'm using the FragmentTabsPager from the class in the link, so basically, it's a Fragment with a TabHost where each page in the TabHost is a fragment. I'm trying to get the Fragment within the TabHost to react to a message received in the FragmentTabsPager Fragment. So, yes I'm trying to update the UI in the Fragment but this Fragment is contained within a TabHost contained within another Fragment.

Comment: I've managed to achieve it using a BroadcastReceiver in the Fragment but it feels kind of dirty..

Answer (score 3):

I FOUND THE ANSWER FINALLY!

To pass a message to the internal fragments, you simple invoke a public function within it. The tricky part comes when looking for the **correct** fragment!

So, to first get the fragment, add this within the CustomFragmentPagerAdapter :

```
    public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements .. {
..

public Fragment findFragment(int position) {
            String name = "android:switcher:" + mViewPager.getId() + ":" + position;
            FragmentManager fm = ((FragmentActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager();
            Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(name);
            if (fragment == null) {
                fragment = getItem(position);
            }
            return fragment;
        }
```

Then access the fragment from the main activity like so

```
CustomFragment fragment = mTabsAdapter.findFragment(1);
if(fragment != null)
   fragment.customFunction(args); //<-- your custom function
```

Please do note that, I'm actually using ActionBarSherlock for all the fragments classes. But this is will still able to solve your problem.